# Polars dataframe: rolling_sum look ahead

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to calculate `rolling_sum`, but not over x rows above the current row, but over the x rows below the current row.

My solution is to sort the dataframe with `descending=True` before applying the `rolling_sum` and sort back to `descending=False`.

**My solution:**

```
import polars as pl

# Dummy dataset
df = pl.DataFrame({
        "Date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Close": [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1],
        "Company": ["A", "A", "A","A", "A",  "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"]
    })

# Solution using sort twice

(
    df
    .sort(by=["Company", "Date"], descending=[True, True])
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Close").rolling_sum(3).over("Company").alias("Cumsum_lead")
    )
    .sort(by=["Company", "Date"], descending=[False, False])
)
```

**Is there a better solution?**

With better I mean:

- more computational efficient and/or
- less code / easier to read

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I just thought of one other solution which is avoids sorting / reversing the column altogether: using `shift`

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Close")
      .rolling_sum(3)
      .shift(-2)
      .over("Company").alias("Cumsum_lead"))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid sorting the rows and instead reverse the specific column twice using [`pl.Expr.reverse`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.reverse.html).

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Close")
        .reverse().rolling_sum(3).reverse()
        .over("Company").alias("Cumsum_lead")
    )
)
```

For readability, this could also be wrapped into a helper function.

```
def rolling_sum_lead(expr: pl.Expr, window_size: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return expr.reverse().rolling_sum(window_size).reverse()

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        rolling_sum_lead(pl.col("Close"), 3).over("Company").alias("Cumsum_lead")
    )
)
```

*Note.* On my machine, this takes 124 µs ± 5.67 µs per loop in contrast to 205 µs ± 6.9 µs per loop for the solution using `pl.DataFrame.sort`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about `reverse`. Also thought about another solution using `shift`

Comment: @FredMaster Good idea and a bit faster as well (106 µs ± 3.2 µs per loop). In this case, I would either edit my answer or delete it and you can post + accept your own solution?